# err when run urg_node

Tags: hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys when i connect the 04lx laser and run urg_node this error occurs "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): vector::_M_fill_insert Aborted (core dumped)"
what can i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78496/err-when-run-urg_node/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered on Github issue ticket here:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/issues/5

Please provide a list of your current parameters, as well as the specific device and firmware version for your Hokuyo.

Additionally, please check permissions on /dev/ttyACM0 by running 'sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0'.

It's also possible your laser is communicating using SCIP 1.0, please try updating the firmware on your laser to the latest version. See more information here:
http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/hokuyo-node-error-td921464.html

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-11**:
i update my laser scip and that's work correct but i write this command "rosrun rviz rviz"
but i do not see any thing how can i see the laser data?
is need another command i run these command
"roscore" "rosrun urg_node urge_node" "rosrun rviz rviz"

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-09-12**:
In RVIZ, change the global frame_id to 'laser' and add a "New Display", and switch the topic to '/scan'

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-12**:
I'm beginner in ros can you tell me how to change these?